# Highcharts: Control show/hide of a div by clicking pie chart slices

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a pie chart. What I am trying to do is show/hide a ul upon clicking a slice. The ul will contain extra data unique to each individual pie slice, so I want the show/hide activated only on its slice.

Also, the ul will be able to be closed upon clicking, but I also want it to put its corresponding pie slice back into the pie. Sounds easy enough but I'm just not quite sure how.

I'm thinking I have to get some unique id's and map those to my open/close function? Could someone help point me in the right direction? Is this explained well enough?

html:

```
<ul class="chart_data">
     <li>one</li>
     <li>two</li>
     <li>three</li>
     <li id="hide">close table</li>
</ul>
```

Chart code:

```
plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function () {
                        show_table();
                        this.select();
                        chart2.tooltip.refresh(this);
                        return false;
                    }
                }   
            },
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            showInLegend: true,
            slicedOffset: 40
        },
        series :{
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function() {
                        show_table();
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
```

and the show/hide functions:

```
function show_table() {
    $('.chart_data').toggle('slow');
    // there is other irrelevant stuff to this function, styling of the ul, etc.
};

$('#hide').click(function() {
    $('.chart_data').hide('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can select and deselect slices with

```
 chart.series[0].data[index].select();
```

where `index` represents slice's order.

see [example](http://jsfiddle.net/qw3R5/28/)

Comment: Ah, yes. I had the select(); in there at one point, but I wasn't getting the index. Thanks so much Eugen.